# Remember/Forgot Password

Tags: magento-1.9, wordpress

I want user to be able to retrieve password for login in a way that it should be same for magento and wordpress. My site front end is in Wordpress and store is in magento. is there any way that a user will be able to generate request of lost password or login request from either of the cms and it applies on the both cms. I am open for plugins. Right now login request is working smoothly for both cms. I am facing problem with forgot/remember password. I am stuck in Logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How WordPress stores user password: md5(passwordvalue)

How WordPress stores user password: md5($salt . passwordvalue) . ":SC";

If we keep $salt value blank and don't use ":SC" for concatenation, then format of customer's password in magento will also be md5(passwordvalue).

Now you can make use of Events and Observers of Magento and Hooks of WordPress to catch event of forgot password and play with code to make it happen.

BEST OF LUCK

If you have any problem please let me know.